# Domain Key Entries

Tags: bind, dkim

More BIND DNS questions.

OK, my changes the the zone files are no propagating out. Now I'm having a problem with the domain key entries I'm trying to create. I'm starting by trying to set the domain key policy. To do so I added the following entry to my zone file (actual domain XXX'd out).

Based on everything I've read this is properly formatted and should work. When I try to verify the DNS entry for our domain it doesn't how up.

```
_domainkey.XXXX.com      TXT     "t=y; o=~;"
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Nate

Answer (score 0):

Unless your origin is ".", you need a trailing period on the hostname. Also it's odd to add FQDNs to a zone file. Usually you just use RDNs and let the origin fill in the rest.

If you're going to keep needing to do BIND administration, might I suggest picking the definitive book on the subject: [DNS and BIND](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100574). Previous editions cover what you need as well, and are pretty cheap.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will certainly pick up that book. I'm still having problems with those domainkeys entries.